# Error found "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement(Opencv lib)"

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.0, google-play-console, opencv3.1

[image: This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement]

**The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 5.
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app**

Found this error while upload APK on play store.
We have use OpenCV Lib for image reorganization.

Can anybudy help to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, @Rajesh this error came because Opencv Lib have only 32bit and possible to not have 64bit lib of Opencv in your project. So, please check your project(app/src/main/jniLibs) check this folder for armeabi-v7a(32bit) and arm64-v8a(64bit) may be this one is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error came because **Opencv** Lib have only 32bit and possible to not have 64bit lib of **Opencv** in your project. So, please check your project`(app/src/main/jniLibs)` check this below folder

> armeabi-v7a(32bit)

and

> arm64-v8a(64bit)

may be this one is missing.